# OpenGL 2D Stencil

Tags: java, opengl

I'm working on a scroll-box in minecraft.

[image]

The scroll-box has one problem, some controls will render outside of the box, so i decided to look up if it's possible to prevent that.
I found stencils, but it doesn't work out, maybe i did something wrong?

```
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glClearStencil(0);
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GL11.glStencilFunc(GL11.GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);
    GL11.glStencilOp(GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_REPLACE);
```

and this is the line of rendering the scroll-box background:

```
    Vector4d color = new Vector4d(140, 140, 140, 255);
    RenderHelper2D.drawGradientRect(1, 1, this.width-1, this.height-1, color, color);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6yZm.png (It's the black outlined gray pattern)

```
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
    GL11.glStencilFunc(GL11.GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
    GL11.glStencilOp(GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP, GL11.GL_KEEP );
```

render all objectives inside the scroll-box (the buttons). Which shouldn't be shown outside of the box.

```
    gui.drawForeground(renderer);
```

and reset everything

```
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
    GL11.glColorMask(true, true, true, true); 
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [glScissor](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScissor.xml)

It lets you basically assign a rectangular cropping window on your screen, and whatever you draw, nothing will ever be drawn outside of this rectangle.

Don't forget to call `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)` before and `glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)` after you draw your scroll box. It won't work without the enable, and it won't stop without the disable ;)

Keep in mind that the values supplied to glScissor are integers for the origin and the width and height of the desired cropping window, the origin being defined as the lower left. Thus,

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)
glScissor(0,0,100,100)
:: DRAW YOUR CONTROLS HERE ::
glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)
```

will create a 100x100 cropping window in the lower left corner of your screen.

You can use stencilbuffers if you want, but those are for more complicated tasks. Since UI usually works with rectangles, glScissor is perfect for it.

Comment: Thanks. It's working, really nice and simple answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a square. The scissor region is a rectangle, where width and height can be different.

Comment: Oops, you are absolutely right Reto. I meant rectangle!

Comment: Is there a way to rotate the scissor?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to rotate it. If you want that, I suggest moving back to stencils